# Monitoring Linux user activities and auditing them

Tags: linux, monitoring, audit

`var/log/secure` provides us below information :

```
Mar 20 08:07:07 testing sshd[29749]: Accepted password for oracle from 10.51.1.12 port 49239 ssh2
Mar 20 08:07:07 testing sshd[29749]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user oracle by (uid=0)
Mar 20 08:12:16 testing sshd[29759]: Received disconnect from 10.51.1.12: 11: Disconnect requested by Windows SSH Client.
Mar 20 08:12:16 testing sshd[29749]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user oracle
```

But what commands that `oracle` user executed we can not get from the above information?

`/home/oracle/.bash_history` provides us information like this about what commands are executed:

```
cat /u01/up_apps.sh 
cd daily/work
less Auto_Clone.log 
cat Auto_Clone.log 
exit
exit
cat /home/oracle/ashfaq/Auto_Clone/Auto_Clone.sh 
cat /u01/down.sh 
cd /u01/oracle/inst/apps/TESTING_testing/admin/scripts/
./adstpall.sh apps/apps
./adstrtal.sh apps/apps
cat /home/oracle/ashfaq/Auto_Clone/Auto_Clone.sh 
cat /home/oracle/ashfaq/demo/main_exec.sh
cd /home/oracle/ashfaq/demo/
ls -ltr
cat main_exec.sh
```

but does not tell us that user from which IP or hostname and at
what time executed these commands.

Can we create some custom file where we can store all this information in one file with time, IP, user name (`root`, `oracle`, `ricky` ) and commands executed by these users ?

Answer (score 4):

There is a tool for this. It's called `audit`, and it can log a very great deal of information, for one or more specific users or for all users. However, since the audit rules will be checked for each syscall on the server, it can mean a decreased performance. It also doesn't include IP information; in order to get that, you would need to combine the audit log with the SSH log to see from which IP the user logged in.

Information about how to apply audit rules can be found by running `man auditctl`.